# Join table with itself in Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I need to join a table with it self to get a correct result.

My table (brands) is:

```
id   |    name    |   replace_by    |   active
```

Brands are related to a Webshop. I need to get the active brands related to a webshop. But if a **inactive** brand is **replaced** by another brand, I need that in my result as well, even though it's not related.

I've tried the following, but it doesnt give me a result. Without the join, it works fine but the "replaced by" is not included.

```
        $webshop = Webshop::select()
        ->where('slug', $slug)
        ->with(['comments' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        }])
        ->with(['brands' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('brands.active', 1)
                ->where('brands.replace_by', NULL)
                ->join('brands as b2', 'b2.id', '=', 'brands.replace_by')
                ->groupBy('brands.id');
        }])
```

Comment: Do you need the `replace_by` brand in the result ONLY when active is null/0?

Comment: `where('brands.replace_by', NULL)` I would have thought this means `'brands.replace_by is null`, therefore can't have any matching replacement. I would get rid of this criterion.

Comment: Laerte: No, I need the row that the replace_by id refers to.

Comment: Shadow: Yes, that clause would need to be removed and replaced by something that joins the id that the replace_by id refers to

Comment: I thought that would be accomplished by the join one line below the one I cited.

Comment: Shadow: No, cause then all the inactive without a replace_by will also be shown.